# Session problems when developing separate Frontend and Backend. (port)

Tags: node.js, redis, nuxt.js

I understand that cookies are managed on a per domain basis. But I don't know why the situation below is a problem.

I am developing as below.
nuxt (port: 3000)
express (port: 4000)

They both have different folders and run.

I set req.session.name = name on request to express . The value of nuxtServerInit req.session of the received nuxt comes out as undefined .

What did I do wrong?

Comment: We will probably need more debugging details here. Check your devtools and use some `console.log` to narrow down the issue.

Comment: The headers information of these two is different.

It seems easy to move forward once you know why this happens. Could you please help?

Comment: We will need some debugging details here.

Comment: We are working on merging nuxt and express, which is the method recommended by nuxt, into one folder.

I wanted to do nuxt and express separately, but it's too difficult for me.